Calculating weighted cosine similarity between vectors of words
I have two word lists, where each word makes up a topic, and has a tf-idf weight for that topic:
topic1 = [('blue',.1), ('red',.05), ('sky',.01)]
topic2 = [('water',.5), ('fire',.1), ('earth',.02)]

I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity between the vectors, but also account for the tf-idf weighting of each word.
Is there a commonly accepted way to account for individual weightings when doing vector similarity? How would I implement this?

What exactly are does numbers next to each word? You want to count CDS out of those numbers? Or they are tf-idf weights and CDS is to be calculated using some other numbers, but somehow include those weights? I have trouble understanding what you want to achieve and what is your "input data"

maybe you should ask on similar portal DataScience and CrossValidated

These are the words mode representative of each topic. A topic is created from a collection of documents (tweets in this case). Not all words would’ve appeared an equal number of times in the collection of documents. I want the words with higher weights to have more influence on the cosine similarity score.

@furas Thanks, I was thinking that this might not be the right place, since it’s not just an implementation question.
